# Collect user selection elements

Tags: revit-api, revit

in version Revit2016
I have a problem, I want to collect the user has selected element, instead of letting the user re-select, I don't know if there is any way to solve it, just like I want to collect the information of the two columns selected on the way. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: blob:https://stackoverflow.com/55db7803-2885-4c7f-aa9b-85da44bc52f2 thank you comment , I hope to get these selected components, the node with the API will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveDocument.Selection.GetElementIds()  (or something close to that) - will be able to tell you the pre-selected elements when you start your command.

Comment: Oh！This is indeed the method, thank you for your answer.